# Create recursive scalar function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-function

I need a recursive scalar function in SQL Server 2014.
My code is this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Accounting_ToppestLevelID 
(
    @ID numeric(6,0)
)
RETURNS numeric(6,0)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @temp numeric(6,0)
    select @temp = a.ParentID from Accounting_AcntAccount a where a.ID = @ID
    if @temp is null
    begin
        return @ID
    end
    return Accounting_ToppestLevelID(@temp)
END
```

But after executing the code below error will appearance:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure Accounting_ToppestLevelID, Line 34
'Accounting_ToppestLevelID' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

It is a logical error but how I can fix it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server 2014

Comment: This is a performance killer.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Really? But there will not be big data in goal tables, I'll remind your advice for future projects :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the schema prefix, ie.

```
return dbo.Accounting_ToppestLevelID(@temp)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should simply specify function's full name: it is implicitly created in `dbo`
schema if no schema is specified, so your script should be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Accounting_ToppestLevelID 
(
    @ID numeric(6,0)
)
RETURNS numeric(6,0)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @temp numeric(6,0)
    select @temp = a.ParentID from Accounting_AcntAccount a where a.ID = @ID
    if @temp is null
    begin
        return @ID
    end
    return dbo.Accounting_ToppestLevelID(@temp)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a schema explicitly. If you don't use a custom one, default is dbo:

```
return [dbo].[Accounting_ToppestLevelID](@temp);
```